# Django permissions for AbstractUser

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am trying to hide parts of my API (DRF) from the AbstractUser.
Here is my `models.py`:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class User(AbstractUser):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True)
```

Here `serializers.py`:

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username', 'email', 'company', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'date_joined', 'last_login', 'is_active',
            'is_staff', 'groups', 'user_permissions'
        )
```

And `views.py`:

```
class CompanyList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = Company
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer

class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = User
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

So what I'm trying to get - get the JSON for the AbstractUser, but he can only see the company he is assigned to.
How can I do that? I have tried using `def has_object_permission()`, but I'm not really sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the queryset to return user's company only.

```
class CompanyList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = Company
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Company.objects.filter(pk=self.request.user.company.pk)
```